# KeyError: 'client_id' at Earth Engine

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I intend to reimplement the following code: https://github.com/lakshya0904/Crop-Yield-Prediction

Trying to run the Export.ipynb and the following code cell gave me a KeyError: 'client_id'

```
yield_data_path='SOP_download/yield_data.csv' #taken from pycrop
                                                                # putting less entries

yield_data_path = Path(yield_data_path)

exporter = ModisExporter(locations_filepath=yield_data_path)
exporter.export_all()
```

On `exporter = ModiesExporter` I've pasted a Earth Engine code and I it returned the following error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-b44da8da3ef3> in <module>
      4 yield_data_path = Path(yield_data_path)
      5 
----> 6 exporter = ModisExporter(locations_filepath=yield_data_path)
      7 exporter.export_all()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ee/oauth.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
    187     fetch_client = request.Request(FETCH_URL, data=data, headers=headers)
    188     fetched_info = json.loads(request.urlopen(fetch_client).read().decode())
--> 189     client_info = {k: fetched_info[k] for k in ['client_id', 'client_secret']}
    190     scopes = fetched_info.get('scopes') or scopes
    191   token = request_token(auth_code.strip(), code_verifier, **client_info)

KeyError: 'client_id'
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I have created a new Project and pasted a new authorization. It gave me the same error with this on top of the old error:

```
Successfully saved authorization token.
WARNING:googleapiclient.http:Invalid JSON content from response: b'{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 403,\n    "message": "Not signed up for Earth Engine or project is not registered. Visit https://earthengine.google.com/faq/",\n    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"\n  }\n}\n'
WARNING:googleapiclient.http:Invalid JSON content from response: b'{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 403,\n    "message": "Not signed up for Earth Engine or project is not registered. Visit https://earthengine.google.com/faq/",\n    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"\n  }\n}\n'
Earth Engine failed to initialize. Use authenticate in command line.
```

Comment: I thouht credentials would be filled with google code I informed